# How to do I save and get @html.raw div HTML into database using jquery and get

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I need to use a multiline text box for that I using classic div. I Used here `@html.raw` of .net Razor view.
Now I need to get that parent div containing `@html.raw` in HTML format so save in DB using jquery ajax, and get that HTML from DB to bind to a controller.

I tried using `$("#idofDiv").html()` but it didn't work.

```html
<div class="box-footer">
  <button type="button" id="btnSaveNotes" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Submit</button>
</div>
```

```
$("#idofDiv").html();
```

I need to get outer div HTML containing HTML.raw using jquery to pass it using ajax to save into DB. and get using c# to bind it to view.

Comment: What are you doing with the value of `$("#idofDiv").html()`? Where do you send it to the server for saving? Also, aside from the problem, why do you want to store HTML in a database? That's a very large code smell.

Comment: I just want that div HTML in a variable to pass it to the controller method. Otherwise all fine.

Comment: Right, but **how** are you doing that right now? Remember that SO is here to help you debug code, not to write code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a proper solution.

This is my code for div :

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add a property on your model that will contain the HTML:

```
public class SomeModel
{
   [AllowHtml] public string Code { get;set; }
```

Add as a hidden field:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Code)
```

Right before form submit, capture the HTML and store in the hidden field:

```
$("#Code").html(  $("#idofDiv").html );
```

This will grab the HTML and store in a hidden field, which in theory should work.  If not, Code could be a textarea that's not displayed.  DIV elements do not post back directly, so you need a hidden INPUT to do the work.